# Efficiency of Parameterization vs Building Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am working on a search function that searches through 500k+ rows. I am trying to make it as efficient as possible and I'm just wondering which of these two methods is more efficient for the SQL query.

1. Build the where clause of the query in the c# application and pass it as an text query to SQL.
2. Create a procedure with all of the possible where clauses and check (@var = '' or COL = @var)
3. Other suggestion?

I know that it's best to run parameterized queries in SQL because it holds query execution plans in memory, which is why dynamically creating the query didn't seem like the best bet to me.

Comment: Perhaps try both #1 and #2 and test execution with likely inputs?

Comment: If the database is static, you can create an index ( very optimized) file out of the database and load that into memory with a suitable data structures and do the search there and then use the result to get the data from the database. However, if the database is dynamic, a sql stored proc might be better

Comment: You need to read and understand this before attempting this type of thing.http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: You have to try both. It's hard to tell without knowing your table structure, indexes, data distribution, what are commonly sent parameters, etc, etc...  What's best is not always the same...

Comment: Keep in mind that it's going to be a nightmare to index your database if you're sending random queries like that.

Comment: In situations like this, I often build more complex procedures using #temp tables that are filled and used differently based on what parameters are send.

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procedures' Execution plan is calculated by sql server and cached for future use, making subsequent calls much faster. But dynamic sql statements run by application don't get this benefit and each run gets its own execution plan calculated, resulting in performance decrease.

Answering your question: Going with stored procs is more efficient/beneficial.

As an added bonus of stored procs, you would not need to rebuild/republish your app in case of logic change.

**EDIT:** If you're trying to build some kind of a ad-hoc data viewer application, you can find the broadest term that would produce a small subset of results, index by that column(s), create a stored proc. Then return the results into your app layer and use LINQ to further filter the results by N number of columns.

For example, index your table by date. Then run the stored proc and return rows filtered by date range: `WHERE date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`. And then filter the result set in the application using LINQ.

**EDIT2:** On the other hand, if number of expected executions is low (below 60 times per minute), you could use LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework and build the entire thing using LINQ queries.

Comment: On the other hand, queries with lot of  `(@var = '' or COL = @var)` parameters are impossible for SQL Server to optimize. Often sending dynamically build finished query will outperform by a large margin.

Comment: You could do WHERE COL=ISNULL(NULLIF(@var,''),COL). This way if \@var is specified to be non null and nonempty string, COL will be filtered by \@var, otherwise all rows will be returned

Comment: That exactly seems to be my issue. Especially because I have multiple date range values where it has to be `((@beginVar is null or @beginVar <= m.date) and (@endVar is null or @endVar >= m.date))`.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand the problem: stored procs can have multiple parameters

Comment: Sorry, what I mean was that the execution time of the query grows exponentially with each of those date range lines that is added.

Comment: You can index on that column. Just by picking between Stored Proc and Dynamic SQL from app layer, you wouldn't gain a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After testing a few different methods recommended here and based on the link below (Provided by @HLGEM), I went with a stored procedure with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. This has reduced query execution time by quite a bit. It seems that recompiling the query every time helped to optimize the query plan for the specific search criteria.

http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: OPTION (RECOMPILE) will invalidate previously calculated execution plan, resulting in the equivalent of dynamic sql performance.

Comment: Right, the reason I chose to go with this one was because the previously calculated execution plan was not optimized for the changing parameters, so it slowed it down quite a bit. The only reason that I went the procedure route instead of dynamic sql was so that I didn't have to rebuild / republish on logic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters to stored proc instead of creating where clause in C# application. There are various factors to consider while performance tuning like indexing, joins on columns if any etc. You may like to see execution plan as well.